# android: different menu depending on situation

Tags: android, menu

hello i would like to present a different menu in my activity depending on some condition. i tried like this.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    if (specialMode)
    {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menuA, menu);
    }
    else
    {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menuB, menu);
    }
    return true;
}
```

however, i always get the same menu, no matter what the value of specialMode is.

Comment: did you check the value of specialMode by debugger or debug output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

onCreateOptionsMenu is called only once ( upon first creation), try using onPrepareOptionsMenu method it get called every time menu is shown.

Comment: thanks, the only problem is, that it seems to add menuitems to the existing ones.